# Customize the menu by adding items

Tags: menus

I need to display a simple menu like this:

```
<nav class="main">
<a href="/" class="home">
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="company-name">My Company</span> 
    <span class="page-name">Home</span>
</a>
<a href="one-page">One page</a>
<a href="two-page" class="selected-current">Two page</a>
<a href="three-page">Three page</a>
<a href="about">About</a>
<div class="account">
    <a href="login" class="login">Login</a>
</div>
```

For this I proceed in this way:

/theme/function.php

```
<?php
// Adding Log in/out links to a Specific WordPress Menu
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<div class="account"><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'" class="login">Logout</a></div>';
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<div class="account"><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'" class="login">Login</a></div>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

/theme/header.php

```
<nav class="main"><?php
$menuParameters = array(
  'theme_location' => 'primary',
  'fallback_cb'     => 'starkers_menu',
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);
echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a><div>' );
?></nav>
```

I can not manage the class pages for current and the tags (span) for the first url (home).

Thank you in advance for your help.

cordially

Comment: Can you be more precise about what the problem is?  Also, what is the purpose of `strip_tags()` on the menu?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you have to extend the [Walker_Nav_Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu) class.

First, create a class that extends the Walker_Nav_Menu

```
/**
 * Custom nav menu.
 * Code copy-pasted from /wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php
 * 
 * @package WordPress
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @uses Walker_Nav_Menu
 */
class User16975_Custom_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    /**
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference.
     */
    function start_lvl(&$output) {}

    /**
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::end_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference.
     */
    function end_lvl(&$output) {
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param object $args
     */
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    }
}
```

Then, implement the `start_el` function following your needs.

Finally, make WP use your class instead of the default one :

```
add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'user16975_walker_class');
function user16975_walker_class($class){
    return "User16975_Custom_Menu_Walker";
}
```

You can also implement `end_lvl` in your class to append the login link.